# How to store an input text value and use it in different components Mobx?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

Below is a component that is an input button; It accepts string input. Since I'm using create-react-app v3.0 I'm using mobx without decorators. Because I'm new to mobx I don't know how to store the state of the string value so that I can reference it in other components.

**Below is the code:**

```
export  class NumberButton extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
        this.state = {
           value: null
        };

        }  



    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="content-section introduction">
                    <div className="feature-intro">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="content-section implementation">
                    <div className="content-section implementation">
                        <h3 className="Number"> Number</h3>
                     {/*takes and stores input in value*/}   <InputText  type="text"  value={this.state.NumberValue} onChange={(e) => this.setState({ NumberValue: e.target.value })} style={{width: "105%", height:"40px", }} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

}

**How would I take the state of the value and store it, so that I can use it in other components? Any help is appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use MobX for that purpose you can create separate store that controls its state:

```
import { decorate, observable, action } from 'mobx';

class ButtonStore {
    value = null;

    setValue(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

decorate(ButtonStore, {
    value: observable,
    setValue: action
})

export  class NumberButton extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
    }  

    render() {
        const { store } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="content-section introduction">
                    <div className="feature-intro">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="content-section implementation">
                    <div className="content-section implementation">
                        <h3 className="Number"> Number</h3>
                        <InputText type="text"  value={store.value} onChange={(e) => store.setValue(e.target.value) } style={{width: "105%", height:"40px", }} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Then in your parent component state you would just instantiate that store:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            buttonStore: new ButtonStore()
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <NumberButton store={this.state.buttonStore} />
    }
}
```

Another simpler way is to use [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) for handling that input.

Please note that this code is not tested, just an idea!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Context to store values between many nested components.

https://pl.reactjs.org/docs/context.html